# Bootstrap inconsistent in image, font and border size

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is an image of how a website I'm coding looks like. I'm using a bootstrap template and have read about how it uses normalize.css to create consistency across browsers.

However, if you look on the right browser (chrome) on the image, you can clearly see that the border, padding, font is larger than the browser on the left (Safari). Not only that, the images are also different in size; Images on Chrome are much larger using the exact size of the image itself while safari respects width=140 height=140 settings.

My question is, what am I missing? How can I get the webpage to look consistent across the board? I want it to look more like the Safari version. I also want images to look sharp. Currently I'm using an image that is 4 times of the intended display size (140x140) in attempts to preserve quality. Is this a good method? If not, what should I do?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Have you zoomed in on the Chrome browser? Check for a magnifying glass icon in the right of your address bar. This isn't Bootstrap's fault.

Comment: Doh! That was the problem.  Thanks.